# The sdk platform-tools (23.1) is too old to check APIs compiled with API 24; please update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-7.0-nougat, platform-tools

I am getting this error on the latest version of Android Studio and while I have installed both Android SDK Platform API 24 Revision 1 and Android SDK Build-Tools 24.

I have also tried File>Invalidate Caches/ Restart... and Build>Rebuild Project.

EDIT: I have also followed all instructions under [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html?utm_campaign=android_launch_npreview_061516&utm_source=anddev&utm_medium=blog#next), but I still get this error.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's not an error. It's just a warning given by Android Studio since the

```
compileSdkVersion 24
```

is greater than the

```
sdk platform-tools version 23.1
```

sdk platform-tools 24 have not yet been released by Google. Once, they are released, you can update it and the warning will be gone. For now, you can make the following changes in the gradle file and continue with your project.

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion 23.0.3
targetSdkVersion 23
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
```

Updated Answer:
Google has now released

```
sdk platform-tools 24
```

You can download the update from SDK Manager and make the following changes to the gradle file

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion 24.0.0
targetSdkVersion 24
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
```

Comment: So this means that I still can't compile an app that is supported in Android N?

Comment: This is incorrect. http://android-developers.blogspot.no/2016/06/android-n-apis-are-now-final.html

Comment: It doesn't mean that you cannot compile an app for Android N. You can do it, but the sdk platform-tools 23.1 won't be able to check for the latest android 24 API's which however are not yet released. As I told you, it's just a warning by Android Studio. You can ignore it and continue building your app.

Comment: Do I have a problem if the error does not go away? Because when I run the HelloWorld default project it runs fine on Nexus 6P running Android N (6.X) API 24. What I'm trying to say is should I try to fix this or does it still work this way?

Comment: @NicolasKadis you can ignore it as of now. It's just a warning.

Comment: @NicolasKadis You can make the update now, it has just been released ! though I didn't found any source of information on it...

Comment: i can't find my device when i use platform-tools 24.0.3. can you my problem? ADB not detected

Answer (score 3):

1. Open SDK Manager
2. Go to system settings > Android SDK
3. Go to SDK Tools Tab
4. you will find Android SDK platform-Tools 23.1 and you will find an update available
5. just update it

cheers

Answer (score 2):

There's no platform-tools version 24 released yet.

To get rid of the warning, you can install currently available platform-tools 24rc1 from the Tools preview channel in the SDK manager.

From the command line it can be installed with

```
android update sdk -u -a --filter platform-tools-preview
```

Comment: but why when i use platform tools 24.0.3 i can't find my device? ADB Device not found.