# How to change Platform-TOOLs

Tags: android

I'm building an app with Android Studio.
This is my grandle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
}
```

If I try to start my application, I can use it never problem.
If I try to upen all view.xml file, I have this error:

```
The SDK Platform-TOOLs version (23.1) is too old to check APIs compiled with API 26; please update more....
```

How can I change Platform-TOOLs and fix my problem ?

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33184819/the-sdk-platform-tools-version-23-is-too-old-to-check-apis-compiled-with-api

Comment: thanks you I have fixed my problem

Answer (score 1):

1. Open SDK Manager
2. Go to system settings > Android SDK
3. Go to SDK Tools Tab
4. you will find Android SDK platform-Tools 23.1 and you will find an update available
5. just update it

As also reported in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40342461/3172725)